# Python Pandas 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am new to Python and was trying the Pandas library. Here is the code to read a CSV file without headers:

```
import pandas as pnd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

pnd.set_option('max_columns', 50)
mpl.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2

headers = ['OrderId', 'OrderDate', 'UserId', 'TotalCharges']
dtypes = {'OrderId': 'int', 'OrderDate': 'str', 'UserId': 'int', 'TotalCharges':'float'}
parse_dates = ['OrderDate']
df = pnd.read_csv('Raw_flight_data.csv', sep='\t', header=None,
                  names=headers,converters=dtypes,parse_dates=parse_dates)
```

This code gives me an error :-

```
runfile('C:/Users/rohan.arora/Desktop/Python/example.py', wdir='C:/Users/rohan.arora/Desktop/Python')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-47-43fc22883149>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/rohan.arora/Desktop/Python/example.py', wdir='C:/Users/rohan.arora/Desktop/Python')

  File "C:\Users\rohan.arora\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\rohan.arora\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/rohan.arora/Desktop/Python/example.py", line 13, in <module>
    names=headers,converters=dtypes,parse_dates=parse_dates)

  File "C:\Users\rohan.arora\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\rohan.arora\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 401, in _read
    data = parser.read()

  File "C:\Users\rohan.arora\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 939, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)

  File "C:\Users\rohan.arora\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1508, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 848, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:10415)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 870, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:10691)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 947, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:11728)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 1044, in pandas.parser.TextReader._convert_column_data (pandas\parser.c:13129)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 2115, in pandas.parser._apply_converter (pandas\parser.c:28771)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I am  using Anaconda Spyder 3.1.2 and running Python 2.7.13.

Comment: I think you want: `dtypes = {'OrderId': int, 'OrderDate': str, 'UserId': int, 'TotalCharges':float}`, the dict values need to be types not str

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need remove `'` for `types`, not `string` representation of `types`:

```
dtypes = {'OrderId': 'int', 'OrderDate': 'str', 'UserId': 'int', 'TotalCharges':'float'}
```

to:

```
dtypes = {'OrderId': int, 'OrderDate': str, 'UserId': int, 'TotalCharges': float}
```